# Castle Windsor filter optional installers

Tags: castle-windsor

Is there a way to filter installers when using IWindsorContainer.Install( IWindsorInstaller[] )?

The reason I am asking is that I have optional features packaged in installers in the same assembly

Comment: Do you want to filter installers themselves, or components within a particular installer? How do tell what you want to register from what you don't want to register? A custom attribute maybe?

Comment: I think filtering installers, keeping one complete feature within one installer. Custom attribute works but can someone point me to how to plugin a custom "installerfactory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass in an instance of a type that derives `InstallerFactory` to do the selection for you.